# System.Core Pipe is broken

Tags: c#, sql, database, system, pipe

I currently just inherited some complex code that unfortunately I do not fully understand. It handles a large number of inventory records inputting/outputting to a database. The solution is extremely large/advanced where I am still on the newer side of c#. The issue I am encountering is that periodically the program will throw an `IO Exception`. It doesn't actually throw a failure code, but it messes up our output data.

the try/catch block is as follows:

```
 private static void ReadRecords(OleDbRecordReader recordReader, long maxRows, int executionTimeout, BlockingCollection<List<ProcessRecord>> processingBuffer, CancellationTokenSource cts, Job theStack, string threadName) {
        ProcessRecord rec = null;
        try {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = threadName;

            if(null == cts)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Passed CancellationToken was null.");

            if(cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Passed CancellationToken is already been cancelled.");

            long reportingFrequency = (maxRows <250000)?10000:100000;

            theStack.FireStatusEvent("Opening "+ threadName);
            recordReader.Open(maxRows, executionTimeout);
            theStack.FireStatusEvent(threadName + " Opened");

            theStack.FireInitializationComplete();

            List<ProcessRecord> inRecs = new List<PIRecord>(500);
            ProcessRecord priorRec = rec = recordReader.Read();
            while(null != priorRec) {                           //-- note that this is priorRec, not Rec.  We process one row in arrears.
                if(cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                    theStack.FireStatusEvent(threadName + " cancelling due to request or error.");
                cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                if(rec != null)                                 //-- We only want to count the loop when there actually is a record.
                    theStack.RecordCountRead++;

                if(theStack.RecordCountRead % reportingFrequency == 0)
                    theStack.FireProgressEvent();

                if((rec != null) && (priorRec.SKU == rec.SKU) && (priorRec.Store == rec.Store) && (priorRec.BatchId == rec.BatchId))
                    inRecs.Add(rec);                            //-- just store it and keep going
                else {                                          //-- otherwise, we need to process it
                    processingBuffer.Add(inRecs.ToList(),cts.Token);      //-- note that we don't enqueue the original LIST!  That could be very bad.
                    inRecs.Clear();

                    if(rec != null)                             //-- Again, we need this check here to ensure that we don't try to enqueue the EOF null record.
                        inRecs.Add(rec);                        //-- Now, enqueue the record that fired this condition and start the loop again
                }

                priorRec = rec;
                rec = recordReader.Read();
            }   //-- end While
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException) {
            theStack.FireStatusEvent(threadName +" Canceled.");
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {

            theStack.FireExceptionEvent(ex);
            theStack.FireStatusEvent("Error in RecordReader.  Requesting cancellation of other threads.");
            cts.Cancel();        // If an exception occurs, notify all other pipeline stages, then rethrow
    //      throw;               //-- This will also propagate Cancellation, but that's OK
        }
```

In the log of our job we see the output loader stopping and the exception is

> System.Core: Pipe is broken.

Does any one have any ideas as to what may cause this? More importantly, the individual who made this large-scale application is no longer here. When I debug all of my applications, I am able to add break points in the solution and do the standard VS stepping through everything to find the issue. However, this application is huge and has a GUI that pops up when I debug the application. I believe the GUI was made for testing purposes, but it hinders me from actually being able to step through everything. However when the .exe is run from our actual job stream, there is no GUI it just executes the way it's supposed to.

The help I am asking for is 2 things:

1. just suggestions as to what may cause this. Could an OleDB driver be the cause? Reason I ask is because I have this running on 2 different servers. One test and one not. The one with a new OleDB driver version does not fail (7.0 i believe whereas the other where it fails is 6.0).
2. Is there any code that I could add that may give me a better indication as to what may be causing the broken pipe? The error only happens periodically. If I run the job again right after, it may not happen. I'd say it's 30-40% of the time it throws the exception.

If you have any additional questions about the structure just let me know.

Comment: First, could you please add the try block of that catch? Second is it possible to isolate the conditions that cause the error?

Comment: Stack traces do wonders too.

Comment: Full Try/Catch Block added

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".